# Fetching all pictures of certain artist on mediawiki

Tags: media-queries, mediawiki, wiki, mediawiki-api

Currently I'm looking for a way to fetch URLs of paintings on mediawiki that is authored by Albrecht Durer.

Can you point me to a some explanations, is there any API like "give me all images where artist is Albrecht Durer"?

I have found an imageinfo (http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Properties#imageinfo_.2F_ii), but didn't find how to filter by artist.

Comment: "On MediaWiki" doesn't mean much. Do you want Wikipedia articles? A list of painting titles/whatever (available on Wikidata)? A list of images of said paintings (available on Commons)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a great way to do that. The [structured media data](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Structured_data) project aims at providing exactly this kind of capability, but it is still ways off.

Right now, your best bet is using the category system. [Category:Paintings by Albrecht Dürer](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Paintings_by_Albrecht_D%C3%BCrer) and its subcategories contain the images you are looking for, and you can use the [categorymembers API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers) as a [generator](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Generators) for imageinfo to fetch the URL's. There is no way to get a recursive list though, so you will have to recurse into subcategories manually. To make it worse, the category graph is not guaranteed to be a tree, so you will have to implement things like duplicate filtering and cycle detection.

If the wiki in question is Wikimedia Commons, there are various external tools which can help, such as [CatScan](http://tools.wmflabs.org/catscan2/catscan2.php) or [catgraph](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Nova_Resource:Catgraph/Documentation).